# How can I line my div up to the edge of my picture?

Tags: html, css, image

I am having trouble lining the edge of my div with a border to the edge of my picture.

Before I added the border to my second div it lined up perfectly, but now that I added it there is a gap between the edge of the div and the picture.

```css
.headDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#heading {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 36;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 35%;
}
#navBarDiv {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: limegreen;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border: 10px ridge gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="headDiv">
  <img id="imgBackgroud" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/unturned-bunker/images/4/4c/PEILEVEL.png/revision/latest?cb=20150321082112" alt="background behing heading" height="200px" width="100%" />
  <h1 id="heading">Etowah Unturned Server</h1>
</div>
<div id="navBarDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your bordered div. This will include any borders and padding in the `width` and `height` calculations.

```
#navBarDiv {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: limegreen;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border: 10px ridge gray;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* NEW */
}
```

Now the default `box-sizing: content-box` is overridden, and your borders don't expand the div.

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the width CSS rule for #navBarDiv you'll get the results you want. By default a div element will display at block-level. [A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) You overrode this rule by setting the width of #navBarDiv to 100%.  So when you added a border with of 10px on both the left and right sides of #navBarDiv, the div element displayed 20 pixels longer than you wanted on the right side of the page.